# Do USB Composite devices show up as one, or multiple devices

Tags: usb, usb-device

I'm working on a Composite USB device with HID + CDC device classes in one device. Things are not working 100% as yet, but irrespective op the details of my project, I just have a simple question.

Does a Composite USB devices show up as a single device os as multiple devices when plugged into a PC?

In other words, how many devices should my CDC + HID device show up as, in for example the Windows Device Manager, or my Mac's System Information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what my device manager looks like when set to "View -> Devices by connection":

[image]

As you can see, the generic "USB Composite Device" and "Sierra Wireless HSPA Device" each get broken down into distinct endpoints. The Sierra Wireless device has multiple CDC endpoints and a network adapter.

In the normal view of device manager, it just shows the endpoints and not the intermediate composite devices or hubs.

However, if you have a composite device *but have not installed its driver*, it shows as one device of type "unknown".

Comment: Same on a mac..